# Fade up image doesn't get over the fade out image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 6 images, on hover each image gets replaced by another image which fade up (with jQuery) and gets upon the initial image.

The issue is that when the image fade up, it gets under the original image and not over it.

Since the fade in/out effect works fine, i think this issue belongs to my css code:

**CSS:**

```
#puzz {
    border-color:#000000;
    background-color:#00CC33;
    position:fixed;
    left:20%;
    top:13%;
    width:900px;
    height:650px;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:8px;
    margin:10px;
    line-height:10px;
    width:218px;
    height:218px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#99CCFF;
    /*For IE9 compatibility*/
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.fade div {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="puzz">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img7.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img8.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img2.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img5.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img3.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img4.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img4.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img3.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img5.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img2.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="fade"><img src="img6.jpg" />
                <div><img src="img1.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is what i get:

[image]

**EDIT:**

here is jQuery script i use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // find the div.fade elements and hook the hover event
    $('div.fade').hover(function () {
        // on hovering over, find the element we want to fade *up*
        var fade = $('> div', this);    

        // if the element is currently being animated (to a fadeOut)...
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            // ...take it's current opacity back up to 1
            fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        } else {
            // fade in quickly
            fade.fadeIn(250);
        }
    }, function () {
        // on hovering out, fade the element out
        var fade = $('> div', this);
        if (fade.is(':animated')) {
            fade.stop().fadeTo(3000, 0);
        } else {
            // fade away slowly
            fade.fadeOut(30);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not really an answer but more a suggestion, have you tried `z-index`ing the image you want to pop over the top?

Comment: Can you post your Jquery too?

Comment: Josh has the right idea.. it looks like `z-index` conflicts. depending on how you want them to overlap, you may need to use dynamic `z-index` values to swap depths of elements using jQuery

Comment: @Marcelo: i added jQuery code to the post :)

Comment: @McMaster: I am new to jQuery, can you guide me? I added my code on the post. Please check:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's your code (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/87GPw/2/), with your problem fixed.

I just made a few changes in the CSS to place the a image "above" the other.

Comment: And `margin-left:8px;margin-top:8px;` in `.fade div` to get the image exactly over the original one ;) +1, Thanx a million :))

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `position:absolute`, you need to specify `position:relative` on the parent element `<li>` in order for the origins to match. You should also specify `top:0; left:0;` in the positioned item

Comment: Hi, thanx for your suggestion, actually i tried it already and it gets the image right under the original one (without getting off the `li` bounds), that's the only difference towards my code, so the image still don't get over the original one.

Comment: Here, take a look at my fade code. It gets around this by setting one image as a background, placing another on top: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/